# IE11 XMLHttpRequest do not receive full data from server

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a web application and I came across with a strange problem. The request that I send to my flask app from Google Chrome and Firefox with XMLHttpRequest works as intended but in IE11 and possibly older versions it looks like IE closes the connection before the data is fully transferred. I send post request like this:

```
function getData() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "http://"+window.host+"/text", true);
    req.responseType = "json";
    req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(e){
        if (e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200){
            display(e.target.response.data);
        }
    });
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    req.send(JSON.stringify({"text": "some text"}));
}
```

and receive from flask app like this:

```py
@app.route('/text', methods=["POST"])
def data():
    if request.is_json:
        if "text" in request.get_json():
            for i in request.get_json()["text"]:
                if not re.search(textIntegrity, i):
                    return jsonify({"status": "Unrecognized characters: {}.".format(i)})
                    break
            data = reData(request.get_json()["text"])
            return jsonify({"status": 200, "data": data})
        else:
            return jsonify({"status": "Key 'text' not found."})
    else:
        return jsonify({"status": "Request type is not in json format."})
```

In mozilla and firefox I get the full data and the XMLHttpRequest object states that the response type is json: [Mozilla Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqEjZ.png) but in IE there is no response type and the reponse is cut if it is too long:
[IE Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE7z5.png)

I don't know whether it's the flask problem or the way that IE handles the request, maybe I need to add some headers to flask project but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActiveXObject` objects instead of `XMLHttpRequest` for older IE:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
    // code for old IE browsers
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

I am not sure the above will solve the issue because you already have **IE11 (newer version)**. Why don't you try AJAX call using JS frameworks and see if you get same issue.

I would say, instead of using `XMLHttpRequest()`, use any JS framework/library to make AJAX calls to your flask REST endpoint, because JS frameworks/libraries will take care of these kind of issues with IE. For example **JQuery**, **AngularJS**.

Comment: Thanks for tips, I appreciate, I would use frameworks if I was at the beginning of the project but I have done the ui implementations and everything that left is just getting data and putting them. So I don't want to add any frameworks just for that purpose. I couldn't implement ActiveXObject thing, I tried using angular.js, it worked but I don't want to mess with my code so I went with changing the server a little bit and I ended up sending json data as string and parse it on the client side.

Comment: same UI will work, just use JQuery to pull data store in a JS variable and use on your UI components. Since everything will be JS, you can use any data or variable after getting response from HTTP ajax request.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's just a personal thing, using a framework for just one purpose is unnecessary for me if a workaround thing is available, sure my app will be pretty lightweight and there won't be any plenty javascript calls nor angular.js or any framework will effect the load time not more than 0.1s but as I said, it's just a personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing server side code and client side code a little and made the server to send json data as string and parsing it on the client side.

```
function getData() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "http://"+window.host+"/text", true);
    req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(e){
        if (e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200){
            display(JSON.parse(e.target.response));
        }
    });
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    req.send(JSON.stringify({"text": "some text"}));
}
```

```py
@app.route('/text', methods=["POST"])
def data():
    if request.is_json:
        if "text" in request.get_json():
            for i in request.get_json()["text"]:
                if not re.search(textIntegrity, i):
                    return jsonify({"status": "Unrecognized characters: {}.".format(i)})
                    break
            data = reData(request.get_json()["text"])
            return json.dumps(data);
        else:
            return json.dumps({"status": "Key 'text' not found."})
    else:
        return json.dumps({"status": "Request type is not in json format."})
```

It maybe is just an issue about flask jsonify, the way flask handles the responses or the way IE handles the requests, I don't know, I had the opportunity to edit the server so I went with that way.